# What can I do to find how many distinct users contribute to all the posts and comments this query seaches for?

Tags: support, data-explorer, users, winter-bash

I have used the query below to form a result table and now I need to find how many users are contributing to it. Is there any way I can achieve that?

```
SELECT p.Title,p.Body,c.Text
FROM Posts p
JOIN Comments c ON c.PostId = p.Id
--  filter on tags
inner join posttags pt on pt.postid = coalesce(p.parentid, p.id) -- find question
inner join tags t on t.id = pt.tagid
-- 
WHERE p.Body like '%Winter Bash%'
AND p.CreationDate < '2020-12-01'
And p.CreationDate > '2011-12-01' 
AND t.tagname like 'winter-bash%'
ORDER BY p.CreationDate ASC
```

Answer (score 6):

The `Posts` table has a `OwnerUserId` column which tells you who is the author of a post. Similarly, `Comments` has a `UserId` column.

If you want to know which users wrote a comment under a Winter Bash post, you'll need

```
SELECT DISTINCT(c.UserId) AS [User Link]
```

If you're looking at post authors instead, you'll need

```
SELECT DISTINCT(p.OwnerUserId) AS [User Link]
```

In both cases, you need to remove the `ORDER BY` line.

The `[User Link]` is a [handy SEDE feature](https://data.stackexchange.com/help#magic-columns) which turns the results into clickable links to profile pages. See [this example](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1354300):

[image]

You might have read it already, but if not, have a look at the great [tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) written by Monica Cellio. Also, remember that SEDE is updated only once a week, on Sunday morning, so you might miss some of the newest posts.

Comment: Does this also include editors?

Comment: @Luuklag, no you would need to join with the `PostHistory` table for that. It's doable but I'm not 100% what the OP is after.

Comment: What if I want to find the reputation of each distinct users? Is there any way?